# How to set virtual memory allocation (vmalloc) on Linux to avoid kernel driver crash

Tags: drivers, kernel

I am working on the Linux kernel loading an new type of video driver. I initially loaded the driver on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 (32-bit) via the following command:

`$sudo insmod myDriverName.ko myParam`

The result of this command produces a "killed" in the terminal. Looking at the dmesg (kernel message), I found the following:

[ 239.265508] vmap allocation for size 67112960 failed: use vmalloc= to increase size

Where should I set the vmalloc ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good answer here: http://thinking-electron.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-increase-vmalloc-size-vmalloc.html

Basically, it is required to set the vmalloc value at boot via Grub.

In /etc/default/grub change the following line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash vmalloc=512M" this will increase the total vmalloc available to 512MB instead of 128MB (by default)

After the new value is set, do a `$sudo update-grub` to regenerate the proper Grub configuration file. Reboot the machine and test the driver out again. The problem should be gone and the driver should come up without issues.